# При replace фрагментов падает приложение Timer

Tags: android, android-fragment, таймер

В моём приложении есть несколько фрагментов которые я переключаю в боковом меню, и в одном из фрагментов у меня есть ViewPager, в котором Timer автоматически перелистывает страницы(каждые 5 секунд), но есть проблема, когда я меняю фрагмент:

MainActivity.java

```
fragmentmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentmanager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, 
fragment).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
```

Через несколько секунд приложение падает, и логи говорят, что Timer во всем виноват:

Log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-1
Process: ru.zoomania.app, PID: 20391 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
at ru.zoomania.app.fragments.MainFragment$100000002$0$debug.run(MainFragment.java:129)
at ru.zoomania.app.fragments.MainFragment$100000002.run(MainFragment.java)
at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Вот код таймера

Fragment.java

```
TimerTask timertask;
Timer timer = new Timer();

    timertask = new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        int i = vpPager.getCurrentItem();
                        if(vpPager.getAdapter().getCount()-1!=i){
                            vpPager.setCurrentItem(i+1);
                        } else {
                            vpPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                        }
                    }
                });

        }
    };

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timertask, 5000,5000);
```

Моя задача, как то выключать таймер во фрагменте из активити

Comment: В `onPause()` фрагмента останавливайте, в `onResume` запускайте. Думаю так будет логично - если фрагмент приостановлен, то листать страницы ни к чему.

Comment: Я это все делал, и `onDestroy`, и `onDestroyView`, `onPause`, `onStop`, ничего не помогает. По проблема в том, что когда я в `onStop` пытаюсь его остановить он мне возвращает что таймер равен `null`

Comment: Вероятно Вы не записываете его экземпляр в поле класса, а создаёте одноимённую локальную переменную в методе, запускаете и по выходу из метода ссылка на таймер теряется. Попробуйте после создания таймера добавить в этом же методе `this.timer = timer;` (слева имя поля, справа локальной переменной - подставьте свои, если у Вас отличаются). Или покажите весь фрагмент. Не относящееся к вопросу можно убрать, оставить только код, где Вы используете таймер (в том числе Вашу неработающую попытку)

Answer (score 0):

Решение было очень простым, нужно было просто отменять `TimerTask` в `onPause()` или подобном жизненном цикле при уничтожении фрагмента:

```
@Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if(timertask != null)
        {
            timertask.cancel();
            timertask = null;
        } else {
            Log.i("LogYourApp","onPause() timertask is null);
        }
    }
```